# Is there a way to insert a string (specifically a colon) into an integer variable?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a code that automates creating a scheduled task by pulling information from an .ini file using schtasks.exe in powershell. However the starttime parameter has a HH:mm format.

It doesn't accept the time in string format (invalid starttime value) and the : interferes with converting it to an integer.

I pulled the hours and minutes as separate variables (and converted them to integers) and tried to "connect" them with a : which gives me variable reference and unexpected token errors.

I've pulled the time from the .ini and removed the :, converted it to an integer, and then tried the .insert(2,':') which gives me 
"invocation failed, int 32 does not contain a method named insert"

The code itself-

```
schtasks.exe /RU $username /RP $password  /CREATE /SC DAILY /TN 'My Task' /TR 'powershell.exe C:\mycode.ps1' /ST $time
```

Process of pulling the time form the .ini-

```
$pull = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Info.ini' | Select -Skip 2 | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'}

$inttime = [int]$pull

$time = $inttime.Insert(2,':')
```

Is there any way for me to get the : between the integers after pulling them from the file? Thank you.

Comment: `Insert()` is in the string class. You will need to cast back to string to use it --> `([string]$inttime).Insert(2,':')` or just use `$pull`. The `ToString()` method from `Int32` also works --> `$inttime.ToString().Insert(2,':')`

Comment: I'm having a hard time reproducing the "Invalid Start Time" when using a string value- provided the string is a valid time. (IE- $time = '21:00';$time.GetType();schtasks.exe  /CREATE /SC DAILY /TN 'My Task' /TR 'powershell.exe C:\mycode.ps1' /ST $time)

Is it possible your original $pull wasn't formatting the time string correctly? Time isn't an integer, at least not in HH:mm format.

Comment: @Mark I believe you were correct. I redid my pull command and got it to work properly. Guess I was staring at the wrong thing thinking it was right for too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently attempting to use the `Insert()` method from String class on an Int32 object. You will need to cast the variable as a string or convert the value to a string to use the method.

```
$time = ([string]$inttime).Insert(2,':')
# OR
$time = $inttime.ToString().Insert(2,':')
```

If all of the digits you are trying to capture are in groups of 4, you can just perform this insert with your `-replace` operator.

```
$pull = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Info.ini' |
    Select-Object -Skip 2 |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\D+(\d{2})(\d{2})','$1:$2' }
```